# CSS print issues: margins, text, background-color

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm creating a nametag solution, compared to an old method using Word which led to large file sizes and corrupt files. I'm using PHP to get the names from a database and print them out into an html page. The page displays perfectly what I want it too.

My issue is that when printing, text with a background-color applied doesn't work correctly.

I'm using this print style to be able to print background-color: `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`

This works well, until I get to the text.

What displays as 
[image: Page]

on the output page, prints as 
[image: Print]

My CSS:

```
.top-bar {
    width:100%;
    height:0.65in;
    background-color:#FFCC00;
    display:block;
    font-size:20pt;
    line-height:200%;
    font-family: Stencil;
    color:#008000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

I've tried different fonts, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm using windows, printing from Chrome. I'm printing to a PDF using cutepdf, but physical printing has yielded the same results.

Is there any way to fix how the letters are printed?

Comment: If you could put an example online you might get more help.

Comment: I actually found out that it's an error in how Chrome prints, not the CSS. I can print from IE perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

> `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`

This is the solution... Apply it to the surrounding div. Remove the background colour on the text and just have it on the div.